# For every connected space X and an open cover U, every two points has a simple chain containing them

Tags: connectedness, covering-spaces

I am trying to prove this theorem saying: " A space X is connected, if and only if for an open cover U of X, every two points in X has a chain between them". 
I cant prove only if part (a connected space has a simple chain between every two points).
I know to show that for every two points in X , say a,b , i can find a family of open groups Uα in U  such that the union of Uα is connected and contains a and b. But I couldn't understand why there is always a finite group of groups as above.
Any idea?
thank alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a connected space $X$ and an open cover $\mathcal{C}$, define an equivalence relation $\sim_{\mathcal{C}}$ by $x \sim_{\mathcal{C}} y$ if there is a chain from $x$ to $y$. Show that each equivalence class is open. (Of course equivalence classes are nonempty by definition.) Equivalence classes are disjoint; if there were more than one equivalence class, you could easily contradict connectedness.

Comment: Yes, but how can i say this "chain" is not infinite? I can think of the answer when it comes to metrizable spaces. What is the reason in a general space?

Comment: I do not understand your question. Chains are finite by definition. But let me offer another way of saying it. Given a cover, let $R$ be the relation where $xRy$ if $x$ and $y$ both belong to an element $U$ of the cover. This $R$ is reflexive and symmetric. Now consider the transitive closure $\sim$ of $R$, where $x \sim y$ if there are $x_0, \ldots, x_n$ with $x = x_0$, $y = x_n$, and $x_i R x_{i+1}$. This $\sim$ is an equivalence relation and is what I meant by $\sim_{\mathcal{C}}$ in my answer. Apply my reasoning to this $\sim$.

Comment: Thanks, I understood the relation. I'll try clearify my question. It's about the size of the "chain" (I am adding the "" because Chain, as you said, by definition are finite). I am trying to understand why there is no way that in some pathologic case, I could find a connected space X , with an open cover U, and 2 points in X, such that only if you take an infinite open groups Uα of U, then the union of all the Uα will create a connected space that contain a and b.

Comment: (You probably shouldn't use the word "group" because that has a meaning in algebra which makes it confusing here.) I suggest that you read my answer again very carefully, checking that the equivalence classes are open (I didn't say "connected"; let's not even worry about that). If there is more than one equivalence class, then pick a point $a$ in one such class $V$, pick a point $b$ in another, let $W$ be the union of all the equivalence classes except $V$. Then $V$ and $W$ are nonempty, open, disjoint, and cover the space, contradiction.